# PHP can't find the submit button in my form. Undefined index

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

SOLVED!

Seems that I only had to add isset to my check.

```
       if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) {
```

I am validating and processing some date that I want to get from my HTML form.
I placed this form inside a $form variable, this way I can send people back to the register form.
But somehow my PHP can't find my submit button ans gives me the error: undiefined index. Note that the PHP is in the same file as the form.

Because my form is rather long, I just post the submitbutton with the example:

```
    $form = "<form action='register.php' method='post'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type='submit' name='submitBtn' value='Register'></td>
            </tr>       
        </table>
    </form>";
```

Part of my PHP:

```
            if($_POST['submitBtn']) {           
                $firstname = strip_tags($_POST['firstname']);
                $lastname = strip_tags($_POST['lastname']);
                $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
```

Comment: Try `if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']))` and close your conditional `}` - you also need to `echo $form;` somewhere. Plus, `Undefined index... what?` - That's rather b-r-o-a-d.

Comment: Where are your firstname, lastname and username form inputs?

Comment: My form is rather long, I shortened it up a bit. they are present. Let me add the isset, didn't noticed that! Bit this was the solution already! After a few hours of coding, I just stared blind to all the code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Want me to put that comment of mine as an answer? Tell me which part of it worked.

Comment: Edited the post, that was the whole solution, the isset statement. I think you should make a different type of answer, I can't pick these comments as the solution unfortunately.

Comment: Well, answers are usually put in to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Putting in my comment as an answer, because that's how it's done on Stack in order to close a question and be [**marked as solved**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/).*

Instead of `if($_POST['submitBtn'])` you're not checking to see if it [**is set**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Do `if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']))` instead.